# Find unordered_map elements by searching for key struct's members values

Tags: c++, lookup, unordered-map

My application have a map like `std::unordered_map<my_struct *, std::string>` with dozens of thousands elements. `my_struct` has some strings, vectors and other types members.

At some step I need to build a new `my_struct` and then look for the map element which has as key a `my_struct` having same members' values as in my lately build object.

Only way I could get it working was with an additional numeric "ID" member and replacing `std::hash` with custom predicate that just returns it from its `operator()` method. This is not a solution however. There is no way I could know that ID when looking for some element of the map.

This is the test code I wrote (`test_key` = `my_struct`):

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct test_key
{
        std::size_t id; //can't exist in my application
        std::string test_str1;
        std::string test_str2;
        unsigned int test_uint;

        test_key(std::size_t id_, std::string test_str1_, std::string test_str2_, unsigned int test_uint_)
                : id(id_), test_str1(test_str1_), test_str2(test_str2_), test_uint(test_uint_)
        {}
};

struct test_key_hasher
{
        std::size_t operator() (test_key* const& tst_k) const
        {
                return tst_k->id;
        }
};


int main()
{
        std::unordered_map<test_key *, std::string, test_key_hasher> values;
        test_key *tst_k1, *tst_k2, *tst_k3, *tst_k4, *tst_lk;

        tst_k1 = new test_key(1, "something 11", "something 12", 1112);
        tst_k2 = new test_key(2, "something 21", "something 22", 2122);
        tst_k3 = new test_key(3, "something 31", "something 32", 3132);
        tst_k4 = new test_key(4, "something 41", "something 42", 4142);

        values.emplace(tst_k1, "first thing");
        values.emplace(tst_k2, "second thing");
        values.emplace(tst_k3, "third thing");
        values.emplace(tst_k4, "fourth thing");

        tst_lk = new test_key(3, "something 31", "something 32", 3132); //there is no way I could know ID 3 here

        std::cout << values[tst_lk] << std::endl; //Expected output: third thing

        delete tst_k1;
        delete tst_k2;
        delete tst_k3;
        delete tst_k4;
        delete tst_lk;
}
```

I even thought that replacing `key_equal` on `unordered_map` constructor for my own predicate could solve it, but that also doesn't work (I get none of map's values as output). The `key_equal` replacement predicate I wrote is:

```
struct test_key_comp
{
        bool operator() (test_key* const& tst_k1, test_key* const& tst_k2) const
        {
                //debug
                std::cout << tst_k1->test_str1 << " == " << tst_k2->test_str1 << " ?" << std::endl;

                return tst_k1->test_str1 == tst_k2->test_str1
                        && tst_k1->test_str2 == tst_k2->test_str2
                        && tst_k1->test_uint == tst_k2->test_uint;
        }
};
```

Then my map looked like `std::unordered_map<test_key *, std::string, std::hash<test_key *>, test_key_comp>`.

The code above gives me following output when using `test_key_comp` in place of default `key_equal`:

```
something 21 == something 11 ?
something 31 == something 11 ?
```

Looks like it stops on first element...

First output line is very odd, it appears even if I don't try to find or access any element (comment `std::cout` line on `main()`).

I've also tried using `find()` method but result is the same as `operator[]` and `at()`.

**Question**: any advice on why it doesn't work and how should I code it to get what I want done in a fast and efficient manner?

I want to avoid looping through all elements because there will have many of them (dozens of thousands...) and that doesn't look to be the most efficient and fastest way.

**Extra question**: Maybe should I use a string built from `test_key`'s members values as the key for the map? I know that would be easier to code, but would it be more efficient and faster? Real implementation of `test_key`/`my_struct` have `std::map<std::string, std::string>`s, `std::vector<std::string>`s and a lot of members of other types (already a lot of work to compare two of those structs) and putting it all within a single string would be hard do build and parse... I know I must benchmark it, but I would like to get some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to efficiently look up something in a hashed map by something other than the hash?   That's not how they work.

You'll need to pick another data structure -- one that can sort by a something that you want to search by.  It could either be a standalone data structure, or a parallel one -- potentially to your unordered_map, but you have to have something that is organized by what you want to search for or you're going to be doing an exhaustive search.

Comment: That means lookups are always done by comparing the hash of both keys (so an external object, even having same member values, would have different hash - maybe because of different memory addresses)? So I didn't catch the the purpose of `key_equal`...

Comment: @Tiago.SR `key_equal` is to resolve hash collisions.

Comment: @Tiago.SR what juan said -- so after the hash lookup is done, IF there are multiple matches in the bucket, then an additional test is used to determine which one you REALLY meant.  But it's only used among the conflicts for the hashed value.   You could either have another hash, but by the key you want, or you could use a multi-index container like those provided by boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/techniques.html

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to know. So if I must rely on hash and only way to get one as I need is merging all members values and names in a giant string, maybe it's better to use that string as key of `unordered_map` (because generating it as hash on each comparison would take so much CPU and RAM), like said on my "extra question". That looks a poor solution...